# how to set mark by nfq_set_verdict_mark

Tags: iptables

i call nfq_set_verdict_mark  to set mark, then i want use this mark in other chain. but the mark is likely not  active.
my iptables chain as follow:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m length --length 0:1500 -j NFQUEUE --queue-balance 50:53;
iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 17 -j DROP
```

i write a program use to get the packet from NFQUEUE, then match some protocol, eg, when match HTTP, set mark = 17, then call the nfq_set_verdict_mark
nfq_set_verdict_mark(qh, id, verdict, htonl(mark), 0, NULL);

however, the http protocol can't be drop, i thought the mark may be not active. how can i do, mark in program then do some action by mark.
help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this problem had resolved, set mark is ok, the iptables rule is wrong, 
when i replace the

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 17 -j DROP
```

to

```
iptables -m mangle -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 17 -j DROP
```

i can drop the packet marked to 17